# Android: limiting/throttling downloadmanager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm pretty new to android, but there seems to be two main ways to download a file in android, download manager and this method:

```
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    // publishing the progress....
    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

I need to be able to throttle a download on the app's end (large file, low bandwidth), is there a way to do this (preferably in download manager) in either method? If I reduced `data[]` from `[1024]` to `[512]`, would that accomplish it by taking smaller chunks at a time?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can throttle the bandwidth like that. A solution might be to run a low priority thread and execute the download in there. It's a good idea in general to do downloads and other long running actions in a separate thread, either through AsyncTask or otherwise.

Comment: The low priority might work. The download is definitely already in an async task, but I'm worried about the device hogging too much of the user's connection (there may be multiple devices fighting for limited bandwidth).